# Undefined symbols Error when add robovm parse binding into libgdx

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm

I am trying to follow the guide at https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings to add parse into my libgdx ios project.

I have download parse-1.0.0-beta-03.jar and added it into gradle dependencies. However, when I run launchIOSDevice command, I got following error. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
      -[PF_Twitter getAccessTokenForReverseAuthAsync:localTwitterAccount:] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
      -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_BFExecutor_$_Background in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter", referenced from:
      -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTask", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPush.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFUser.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFConfig.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFBlockRetryer.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFRetryingCommandRunner.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPurchase.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFTaskCompletionSource", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFTaskHTTPRequestOperation.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFNetworkCommandRunner.o)
      objc-class-ref in Parse(BFTask+Private.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't added all the required frameworks, more specifically probably Bolts. If your using parse 1.6.1 ensure these are linked libraries:

[image: pic1]

Or you can get a starter project [HERE](https://parse.com/docs/downloads)

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question. He is using the RoboVM, not the xCode